# How to theme back end forms created by a custom module?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to be able to theme a custom form I create using a custom module that builds a form. The form is created programmatically using the code below:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
      '#required' => TRUE
    );

    $form['address'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Address'),
      '#required' => TRUE
    );

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    );

    return $form;
}
```

This form is rendered on the Drupal 8 back-end and uses the admin theme classy `BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/form/form.html.twig'`. However there isn't a override file name suggestion.

How would I theme this form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was looking for a way to use a twig template to theme the form. How
>   would I go about doing that?

First your form needs to have an ID

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
      '#required' => TRUE
    );

    $form['address'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Address'),
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    );

    return $form;
}

public function getFormId() {
  return 'the_custom_form_id';
}
```

Now we create a new suggestion:

mymodule/**mymodule.module**

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_alter
 */
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

    if (isset($variables['element']) && isset($variables['element']['#type']) && $variables['element']['#type'] == 'form') {
        $original_theme_hook = $variables['theme_hook_original'];

        $suggestions[] = $original_theme_hook . '__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']['#id']);
    }

    return $suggestions;

}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */    
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form_id == 'the_custom_form_id') {

      $form['#theme'] = ['my_custom_form'];

    }

}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 */
function mymodule_theme() {

    $themes['my_custom_form'] = ['render element' => 'form'];

    return $themes;

}
```

**Note:** If you're the creator of the form, you can skip the hook_form_alter part and just put `$form['#theme'] = ['my_custom_form'];` inside your form

mymodule/templates/**my_custom_form.html.twig**

```
<div class="something">{{ form.name }}</div>
<div class="something-else">{{ form.address }}</div>
<div class="something-else2">{{ form.actions }}</div>
```

Comment: @Harnamc You're welcome, no prob.

Comment: hey, this works for me kind of, but I am a little confused with your note, where I should place this $form['#theme'] = ['my_custom_form']; inside formbuild function? I tried that and didn't work. If I use form_alter then I can't save fields information on database. Can you help me with this? thanks

Comment: @Pedro Hmm, yes try putting it in the build function, but without the named wrapped in an array. `$form['#theme'] = 'my_custom_form';` If it still doesn't work, then maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I am passing theme value inside an array like this
$form['module']['admin_theme'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'admin_form'
    );
And twig file is loaded, but now I can't call my fields like you explain {{ form.name }}
My fields appear but like an admin form as usual
If I apply alterForm I can load my fields like you said, but submit button is not doing anything, any ideas for submit button not working (save values in database) ?

Answer (score 4):

One option is to add a prefix and suffix to your form arrays

```
$form['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
  '#required' => TRUE
  '#prefix' => '<div class="something">',     
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

$form['#attached']['css'] = array(
 'path/to/my.css' => array(
   'group' => CSS_AGGREGATE_THEME,
   'weight' => 999
 ),
);
```

**my.css**

```
.something { 
  border: solid red;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to use a twig template to theme the form. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

It's an old post but it help me someway, so I will leave my answear, hope it will help someone.

The first answear of this post help me a lot, at the end I simplify some code.

I had same problem when I try to theme my form.

What I have done

MYMODULE.module file.

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'admin_form' => [
      'template' => 'admin-form',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ],
  ];
}
```

The on my form.php (MYMODULE/scr/Form/form.php) inside buildForm function

```
$form['simulator_values']['connection_services'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#maxlength' => 140,
  '#default_value' => $config->get('connection_services'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
];

$form['actions'] = [
  '#type' => 'actions'
];

$form['actions']['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit ss')
];

return [
  '#theme' => 'admin_form',
  'render element' => $form,
];
```

Finally on twig side have to build form like this

```
<form {{ attributes }}>
  {{ form.form_build_id }}
  {{ form.form_token }}
  {{ form.form_id }}
  {{ form['render element'].advanced_info }}
  {{ form['render element'].actions.submit }}
</form>
```

Without form_build_id, form_token and form_id the submit button won't work.

As far I understood drupal need those information about the form to process everything on the right way, because you can have multiple forms on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Formdazzle!](https://www.drupal.org/project/formdazzle) module.

> Drupal form theming with less pain Theming drupal forms can be
> difficult and time-consuming. This module provides a set of utilities
> that make form theming easier.
>
> Currently, this module provides theme suggestions for forms that are
> much more useful than those provided by Drupal core.
>
> - Theme suggestions for all form elements (including buttons)
> - Theme suggestions for all form element labels
> - All theme suggestions include the form ID and the form element name; e.g. `[element-type]--[form-id]--[form-element-name].html.twig`
> - New in 2.1.0! Twig debugging comments have been added to all forms for the hidden [`form-id].html.twig` template.
>
> While Drupal core only provided these two theme suggestions:
>
> ```
> input.html.twig
> input--textfield.html.twig
> ```
>
> Formdazzle adds the following two theme suggestions to the list:
>
> ```
> input--textfield--webform-contact.html.twig
> input--textfield--webform-contact--first-name.html.twig
> ```