# Why is my form submit button being rendered twice?

Tags: theming, 8, forms, input-formats

I have built a form and this is my submit button for it:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Name',
    '#theme' => 'custom_input'
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    '#theme' => 'custom_input'
  );

  $form['#theme'] = 'custom_form_theme' ;

  return $form;
}
```

My custom_module.module file is:

```
function custom_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'custom_form_theme'  => array(
      'render element' => 'form',

    'custom_input' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
```

I have a `/themes/custom/form/input.html.twig` file for inputs and also have a `/modules/custom/custom_module/templates/custom_input.html.twig` to theme the form I am creating. For now they are identical and I am using twig debug to see what template is rendering the elements. twig code below:

```
<input{{ attributes.addClass(text) }} />{{ children }}
```

The name textfield renders correctly and uses my custom modules templates `custom_input.html.twig` (which is what I want) however for the submit input, it gets rendered twice, firstly using my themes `input.html.twig` and then using my custom modules `custom_input.html.twig` so I get 2 button on my page. I dont understand why the submit is rendering twice.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Why does it render twice instead of overriding the /theme/custom twig?

Comment: Not enough code to be able to answer your questions.

Comment: @Jaypan Sorry, updated the question with more info. is that enough or do you need more?

Comment: have a look at [my answer here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226747/how-to-theme-back-end-forms-created-by-a-custom-module/226777#226777), *may* help.

Comment: With your updated code and explanation, I think I see the problem. As you said, both your templates are being called. This is because you are rendering an input, which will call `input.html.twig`, and because you've also added a #theme, which calls `custom_input.html.twig`. You'll may need to define a new custom element type, rather than using #theme, to do what you want.

Comment: @Jaypan thanks for the answer. Do you have a rough code that you can share?

Comment: @4k4 Hi mate. Any idea on this one?

Comment: Here is how to create custom elements: https://www.drupal.org/node/169815